# How to block user agent from accessing my WordPress site with htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, security, user-agent

I have noticed large amount of traffic coming to my site from different IP's with user agent.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SiteExplorer/1.0b; +http://siteexplorer.info/)
```

I don't have much experience with Apache servers and hope someone can explain to me how to actually block this from accessing my site with *.htaccess* file.

I tried with

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^siteexplorer?$" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Blocking a site access by user-agent is a bad idea because you block all users with this user-agent (especially if the user-agent is well known like Mozilla). Try to block IP adresses instead.

Comment: it's robot that changes ip every few hours, so ip based block won't work for me... i don't wanna block mozilla, just siteexplorer...

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression specifies that the string must not have anything before or after the name of the crawler.  That is what the `^` and `$` do.   I'm also not sure why you would have a `?` in there, which makes the "r" at the end optional.

Try this instead:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "siteexplorer" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more than okay to block any agent when the agent is very specific. In this case, you should be safe.

Here is an example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SiteExplorer.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

You will notice that I added `.*` to wildcard any number of characters.

I use this method on a long list of agents where `(agent2-regex|agent2-regex|agent3-regex)` is used to make multiple comparisons. The `()` brackets the conditions and the `|` is an `OR` operator.

Comment: Note that `^.*SiteExplorer.*$` is the same as simply specifying `SiteExplorer` (ie. match "SiteExplorer" anywhere inside the user agent string).

Comment: True. I thought I would correct his usage as it appeared. I prefer the shorter method you pointed out, but I have also made mistakes this way too.